# Double port forwarding kubernetes + docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, kubernetes, psql, portforwarding

Summary:

I have a docker container which is running kubectl port-forward, forwarding the port (5432) of a postgres service running as a k8s service to a local port (2223).
In the Dockerfile, I have exposed the relevant port 2223. Then I ran the container by publishing the said port (`-p 2223:2223`)

Now when I am trying to access the postgres through `psql -h localhost -p 2223`, I am getting the following error:

```
psql: server closed the connection unexpectedly
This probably means the server terminated abnormally
before or while processing the request.
```

However, when I do `docker exec -ti` to the said container and run the above psql command, I am able to connect to postgres.

Dockerfile CMD:

```
EXPOSE 2223
CMD ["bash", "-c", "kubectl -n namespace_test port-forward service/postgres-11-2 2223:5432"]
```

Docker Run command:

```
docker run -it --name=k8s-conn-12 -p 2223:2223 my_image_name:latest
```

Output of the docker run command:

```
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:2223 -> 5432
```

So the port forwarding is successful, and I am able to connect to the postgres instance from inside the docker container. What I am not able to do is to connect from outside the container with the exposed and published port

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a following parameter with your `$ kubectl port-forward ...`:

- `--address 0.0.0.0`

I've reproduced the setup that you've tried to achieve and this was the reason the connection wasn't possible. I've included more explanation below.

---

#### Explanation

- `$ kubectl port-forward --help`

> Listen on port 8888 on all addresses, forwarding to 5000 in the pod
>
> `kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 pod/mypod 8888:5000`
>
> ---
>
> #### Options:
>
> `--address=[localhost]`: Addresses to listen on (comma separated). Only accepts IP addresses or
> localhost as a value. When localhost is supplied, kubectl will try to bind on both 127.0.0.1 and ::1
> and will fail if neither of these addresses are available to bind.

By default: `$ kubectl port-forward` will bind to the `localhost` i.e. `127.0.0.1`. **In this setup the `localhost` will be the internal to the container** and will not be accessible from your host even with the `--publish` (`-p`) parameter.

To allow the connections that are not originating from `localhost` you will need to pass earlier mentioned: `--address 0.0.0.0`. This will make `kubectl` listen on all IP addresses and respond to the traffic accordingly.

Your `Dockerfile` `CMD` should look similar to:

```
CMD ["bash", "-c", "kubectl -n namespace_test port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 service/postgres-11-2 2223:5432"]
```

---

Additional reference:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Reference: Generated: Kubectl commands](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands)*

Comment: thanks a ton @Dawid, especially for the explanation! It worked like a charm.